# Time complexity of solving a linear congruence of $A p + C \equiv 0 \pmod {2^b}$ form

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I'm curious about the best possible computational time complexity of solving a linear congruence of the form

$$ 
A p + C \equiv 0 \pmod {2^b}
$$

where $A$, $b$ and $C$ are all positive integers and $p$ is the variable we are looking for. $A$ is coprime with $2^b$. Also $2^b$ can be arbitrarily large, but $A$ is approximately the same magnitude.

**Update** I'm only looking for a rough estimate. Actually I'm more interested if this can be done in polynomial time depending on $b$. (Modulo is constant time, addition is $\mathcal{O}(b)$, multiplication is $\mathcal{O}(b^2)$.)

Comment: You asked for computational time complexity for a solution, but did **not** tell use what time complexity assumptions you are using for arithmetic operations.

Comment: In a sense it does not make too much difference, but let's assume that addition is $\mathcal{O}(b)$, multiplication is $\mathcal{O}(b^2)$. Modulo with $2^b$ is a constant time operation.